# Putting ListView Row Text Into Variable

Tags: android, string, listview, variables, onitemclicklistener

I can't get my head around this, I can manage to get which row number of the listview is clicked. But I can't figure out how to put the text of the selected list row into a variable. I need this just to move onto content that is specific to the selected list row. Any help or direction would be great,thanks!

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }


        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList); ;        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            { 
                String TEST = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TEST, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                });




        return rootView;        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument in onItemClick() is `position`.
Use this `position` to `.getItem()` from the ListAdapter associated with your ListView.
You can then get the text from that item in the normal way.

**`<Additional>`**

To get the ListAdapter associated with your ListView you would use `arg0.getAdapter()`. So the full method call becomes `arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position)`.

but as ρяσѕρєя K pointed out, you defined your ListAdapter using the ArrayList called songList.
You defined songList is an ArrayList of HashMaps.
So when you call `arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position)`, what will be returned is the HashMap located at that position in your ArrayList called songList.
Since a HashMap is what will be returned, you should write something like:

```
HashMap selectedItemHashMap = (HashMap)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

You can then retrieve the relevant data from the HashMap with:

```
selectedItemHashMap.get(...//The relevant key for the data you want to get out of the HashMap...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm stil coming up with `12-13 07:43:29.645: E/AndroidRuntime(654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-13 07:43:29.645: E/AndroidRuntime(654): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap`  Any ideas?

Comment: Add your new revised version of you code and the full LogCat output to the bottom of your question, to help clarify what is going on.

Comment: Its ok I got it, I don't know why I didn't do it earlier. Thanks for the help
`String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing `ArrayList` of `HaspMap` to `LazyAdapter` so `getItemAtPosition` will return you `HaspMap` at the position of selected row instead of `String`. set select row elements as:

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
       HashMap<String, String> selected_row =(HashMap<String, String>) 
                       list.getItemAtPosition(position);

          String str_title=selected_row.get(KEY_TITLE);
          String str_artist=selected_row.get(KEY_ARTIST);
        //....
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the following error now on line 92 (hashmap line you gave me) `12-13 07:43:29.645: E/AndroidRuntime(654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 07:43:29.645: E/AndroidRuntime(654): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap`